# Disabling hyperlink with css

Tags: html, css

So I have been trying for days to disable some hyperlinks using a css stylesheet. I need them to be just plain text -- I can not change the html.

```
<link href="css/stark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

`<nav id="header_wrapper">`

```
    `<h1 id="logo">`
```

`<a href="#">STARK INDUSTRIES</a></h1>`

```
    `<ul id="navigate">`
      `<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>`
      <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>`
```

Comment: Please post the CSS you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`pointer-events:none;`

in your CSS rule. This will disable the mouse events on that particular element. Read more:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

K K's solution is the right approach, I would just like to add one thing:

```
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
```

The pointer-events:none would stop the anchor from being clickable, however the pointer cursor would still show up when hovered, potentially confusing users into thinking it was clickable. It's best to set the cursor back to default to simulate plain text as closely as possible.

Comment: So I finally finished this one -- one main problem I figured out after changing my code as you and KK said was that the browser I was using for some reason did not support my css stylesheet. I opened Chrome and all of my CSS was in place working fine. Thanks!